Ubuntu 20.04: MySQL 5.7 installed but not updating
I have an Ubuntu 20.04 instance on AWS set up and running well.  For various reasons it needs to be running MySQL 5.7 instead of 8. It is, and has been running MySQL 5.7 well.  However I just discovered that it hasn't been updating maintenance versions of 5.7 for a while. I don't see any obvious reasons why.
The repositories it has been using are:
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools

When it was installed, I followed the recommended advice to prevent MySQL 8 from being installed by adding this:
/etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
Package: *
Pin: origin repo.mysql.com
Pin-Priority: 900  

Package: mysql*
Pin: origin ch.archive.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: mysql*
Pin: origin security.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: -1

It seems all the URLs and paths are correct.  I checked the referenced repositories and they list versions newer than what is installed on my server.  What's going wrong?

The bionic repositories would have been deprecated a while ago as that’s 18.04. The 20.04 location would be focal, which still has another year or so of support.

Thanks for the reply.  Bionic certainly is deprecated, but it still seems to be available: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mysql-5.7/
If 5.7 were available in the focal repository, I would certainly use it.  But it's not:
http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/

I am running into exactly the same issue.. Would have been a small effort to provide the bionic branch with updates, especially since the focal branch does not have 5.7 :(

The weird thing is that when I was still using Bionic using the official Ubuntu APT mirrors, I had a much newer 5.7 release versus now that I am on Focal using repo.mysql.com. So by upgrading my OS I ended up with an older version, how contradicting.
